# Powerpoint VBA makro moving in slideshow mode w. 2 screens + VBA textfields disabled

Tags: vba, powerpoint

My VBA makros in PP works well in slideshow mode on 1 screen, however, disfunctions w. 2 screens. 
Makros either move around on slide or input textbox doesn't work (not able to add input)

The slideshow consist of a textbox input box, a commandbutton, and a textbox output box.
When I change settings on the screens (e.g. change reolution, or which screen to be the main screen), I can make it work again. 
However, all these change of setting and testing is not be possible when doing presentations for a customer.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TextBox2 = TextBox1 * 0.025
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

End Sub
```

I expect the macros to be at place on the screen no matter the screen.

Comment: Regarding "I expect the macros to be at place on the screen no matter the screen.", I suppose you mean you expect the controls to be at place (macros are always in the macro editor). Try using their .Left and .Top properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OLE and OLE Controls are resolution-dependent. PowerPoint can calculate the control's positions differently when resolution changes or when used on mixed-resolution multi-monitor setups. You could possibly get around this by using a VBA userform for controls instead of placing them on the slide.

Comment: I have tried creating a userform in VBA as suggested, but how should I access this userform in the presentation? The only way I could figure this out was to insert a command button(1) on the slide with VBA coding "UserForm.Show" - but then I again obviously experience the same issue with that command button (1) moving around in the slide...?

Comment: You don't need a command button to run a macro. An ordinary Action Button can do that job and will stay the same size in the same position.